# Java HotSpot(TM) 1.8 exception ClassNotFoundException on debug ggts 3.6.1 grails 2.4.3

Tags: java, grails, ggts

Running ggts-3.6.1.RELEASE
       grails-2.4.3
      java_version 1.8
on run-app,

I get this warning:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

On debug as run-app, I get this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM[56287]   
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))
```

How can I suppress the Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM?
How can I stop the `Java HotSpot(TM) ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

The much better question to ask requires that you include the name of the class it can't find: java.util.HashMap$Entry. That's not some obscure class in a jar - it's a JDK class.

This is a bug in Groovy which affects Grails, Gradle, etc. No version of JDK 8 works yet, so for now downgrade to the most recent 1.7 and it should work. You'll want to do a full clean and recompile to ensure there's nothing funky from 1.8 in  class file that keeps it from loading.